# Какой soft использовать для создания VPN для получения доступа к информационной базе 1с7.7 в файловом варианте через Интернет?

Tags: 1с, vpn

Что бы был и бесплатным и много компьютеров можно бы использовать. У (Hamachi is free for up to 5 computers in your network.)
Про NeoRouter нашел вот (Основное преимущество NeoRouter перед Hamachi в том, что при работе с NeoRouter весь трафик идет не через перегруженный сервер разработчиков программы, на котором сидят сотни таких же как вы пользователей, а через **ваш собственный** сервер. Т.е. скорость трафика ограничена только скоростью вашего провайдера, никто его не сможет перехватить и промониторить, а если вдруг сервер Hamachi упадет или встанет на техобслуживание, то вся ваша Hamachi сеть рухнет, а с NeoRouter вы независимы от разработчиков. Технический же принцип один и тот же - организация TCP туннеля через стандартный SSL протокол и создание через этот туннель VPN сети.)
Существует ли что ни будь более оптимально ?

Comment: Openvpn чаще всего используют. Шибко умные ipsec. В арсенале у пингвинятников есть ещё несколько техник построения туннелей. Всякие хамачи - ну это совсем не серьёзно. Это же для школоты в игрушки играть.

Comment: Я бы тоже предпочел OpenVPN

Comment: SoftEther есть.

Answer (score 2):

1с в файловом варианте и через обычный Ethernet работает плохо, когда клиентов больше трех штук. Что же будет, когда вы smb в VPN потащите....

Правильное решение вашей проблемы - терминальный доступ. Там и SSL уже встроенный в протокол. Изучайте RDP.

Answer (score 0):

Когда то очень успешно решили такую задачу развернув маршрутизаторы на специализированной сборке linux - [IpCop](http://www.ipcop.org/). Маленькая, шустрая, легко настраивается через веб-морду.
Связали офис и 9 филиалов в одну сетку. Использовалось для передачи пакетов обмена в основном (пиринг халявный был у провайдера), сброса бэкапов баз.

Если Вам именно для работы в 1С удаленно - действительно, смотрите в сторону RDP, под 7.7 вариантов не много, под 8.3 выбор уже есть =)